# How to find all accessed files in a shell script

Tags: shell, antlr

There is a shell script, and the scipt accesses some files (including shell scripts and text files), finally some files access the other files (only text files).
e.g.,

```
#shell script A 
SHELLFILE=/usr/app/some # shell file
COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd  # shell command
cat $SHELLFILE
...
GET_PATH=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
TXT_FILE="${GET_PATH}/log.txt" #text file
... 


#hierarchical file tree 

                 shell script A [directory 1]
                         |
            ---------------------------
           |                           |
  shell script B [directory 2]   text file [directory 3]
           |
     text file [directory 4]
```

When parsing the root shell script, how can I get a hierarchical file tree listing all the accessed files and their directories ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain I have understood your question, but I think you want to see what files are accessed by a fairly complex shell script throughout some hierarchy.

One way to do it might be to create a *"sentinel marker"* of the time that your script starts, and then at the end, find all files that have been accessed since that marker.

So, at the start of (or even before starting your script if you don't want to modify it) create a file that stamps the current time:

```
touch /tmp/BEGIN
```

then at the end of your script, or even after it has finished, check for files accessed since the start:

```
find . -neweram /tmp/BEGIN
```

Comment: Sorry to have misunderstood you. I want to parse all files appeared in a shell script.

Comment: :-) Ok, sorry, it seems I have misunderstood your needs. I won't delete it, as it may be useful to someone else in the future and it's not doing any harm.